# Import .cer to cacerts using image openjdk - java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, docker, ssl-certificate

Trying to import my cert into cacerts using openjdk docker image. Getting error java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.2-jdk
COPY target/classes/cert/mycert.cer mycert.cer
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8888
```

entrypoint.sh

```
echo "Installing certs to JDK" && \
keytool -importcert -file mycert.cer -alias mycert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

docker build -f Dockerfile -t java_test2 .

docker run java_test2

```
Installing certs to JDK
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/openjdk-17/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: In Java 9 up there is no separate 'jre' directory; use `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`. But note [the docker images _named_ 'openjdk' are deprecated](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) (other images continue to _contain_ OpenJDK)

Comment: I just using wrong path... thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use cacerts in OPENJDK use:

```
$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
```

instead

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```